# Accessing current process instance variable information from Camunda BPMN engine

Tags: java, sql, camunda

I want all the information on the running process instance stored in H2 database under act_proc_in_ table.(like starttime, endtime, author..)

I am in the ExecutionListener method (in class implementing JavaDelegate interface) from where I need to forward the information further.

I know about RuntimeService interface with createExecutionQuery() method but in all the examples I have seen it seems to be mapped to some kind of entity class. I do not understand it. 
Sorry, but I am new to Camunda BPM engine.

```
    public class ProcessRequestDelegate implements JavaDelegate { 
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("LOAN-REQUESTS"); 
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception { LOGGER.info("Processing request by '"+execution.getVariable("customerId")+"'...");
    System.out.println(execution.getVariable("amount")); 
    int Amount= ((Double) execution.getVariable("amount")).intValue(); System.out.println("Amountis"+Amount);

    ProcessEngine processEngine = BpmPlatform.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService(); 

    ResulstSet rs= runtimeService.createExecutionQuery("What to write here?"); 
 while (rs.next()) {
         String author=rs.getString("AUTHOR");
            Date start = rs.getDate("START_TIME");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");

} }
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: I hope this is more readable? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Camunda BPM 7.2 you are able to use the method execution.getProcessEngineServices() to access the [engines services](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-delegation-code-accessing-process-engine-services) in a java delegate class. Use the HistoryService or RuntimeService to create a (Historic-)ProcessInstanceQuery like

`HistoryService historyService = execution.getProcessEngineServices().getHistoryService();
 HistoricProcessInstance historicProcessInstance = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(execution.getProcessInstanceId()).singleResult();`

Then you can access the info on the HistoricProcessInstance.

Be aware that you are querying the database through these services. Data changed in the current transaction is not available through the services until the transaction is committed.

Comment: When i used .singleResult() the code threw an exception. Then, I retrieved the data in a list<HistoricProcessInstance> (to check if I am retrieving anything at all )and surprisingly the size of list is 0. I wonder how could that be ?

Comment: That means the process isn't persisted to the database yet. You are probably still in the first transaction. See [1] for a description what transactions in a context of a process are and how you can influence them. [1]: http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-transactions-in-processes

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked by changing the values of asyncbefore of servicetask to true.